# Finding the most common Values in a list of ndarrays in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to find the most common ndarray in a list of ndarrays.
I tried using the mostCommon() function but I got this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray`.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

example list:

`a = [array([1, 2, 3]),array([1, 10,30,2, 3]),array([1, 2, 3])]`

I want it to print the most common ndarray: `array([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: convert to a hashable type (e.g. tuples if 1D arrays)

Comment: What is `mostCommon()`? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @richardec it's used to find the most common element in a counter. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your arrays, @Prince?

Comment: @mozway I converted it to a tuple and that works thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is really not well suited for such computation as it deals with variable-sized arrays (aka. jagged array). Moreover, the general approach to deal with such problem is to either sort the array or to use a hash-table but Numpy array of different size cannot be natively compared and they are also not trivially hashable.

One trick to deal with such problem is to **convert arrays to tuples** and then use a **dictionary** to count the items. Here is the resulting code:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 10,30,2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
result = np.asarray(Counter(map(tuple, a)).most_common()[0][0])

# result = array([1, 2, 3])
```

Note that this is not very efficient for large list, but using a list of small Numpy arrays is actually what prevent the computation to be fast. At least, the solution is simple.